# PyQt app causes R6031 error on Windows platform

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pyqt, pyinstaller

I am new to PyQt. Recently I encountered a problem. I have searched a lot, but found nothing.

I wrote a script recorder app on the Windows platform with PyQt, and I packaged it with PyInstaller. I start the app, the ui contains a cmd terminal, and when I click the `recorder` button, the app works. But here is also a problem, that when I close the app ui, the cmd terminal is still there, and when I close the terminal, Windows shows the error:

> R6031 - Attempt to initialize CRT more than once. This indicates a bug in your application.

If I don't click this button, the cmd terminal will close with the ui. The button logic code is below:

```
def recorder(self):
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "录制中", None))
    print("title")
    print(len(self.title))
    if(len(self.title)<1):
        print("notitle")
        text, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self.Dialog, 'Input Dialog', 'input title:')
        self.title=str(text)
        print(len(self.title))
        self.s=recorder.Snail(self.title)
    self.s.main()
    return
```

And here is the main method:

```
 def main(self): 
    global locationText
    locationText = Ui_recorders.locationText 
    self.hm = pyHook.HookManager()  
    self.hm.KeyAll=onKeyboardEvent
    self.hm.HookKeyboard()      
    self.hm.MouseAll =onMouseEvent 
    self.hm.HookMouse()        
    global tmptime
    tmptime=time.time()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: tks very much for editing